# How to remove Office 365 On Electron on Ubuntu?

Tags: microsoft-office

Hi can anyone help me out get rid of this i tried all prossible ways to remove but i am not able to remove

Comment: How to uninstall depends on how it was installed. Please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Does the command `sudo snap remove office365webdesktop` work? If it does, I would turn this comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366028/how-to-remove-office-365-on-electron-on-ubuntu#comment2345391_1366028):

```
sudo snap remove office365webdesktop
```

Since this works for me, I'm confirming the comment and posting it as an answer.